# Извлечение значении input и select

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте! Есть такая форма(id='form'). Нужно извлечь значение `input` и `select` и составить массив(примерно: [{1, Главная}, {2, Новости}, ...]) после нажатия на кнопку. Как можно составить такой массив с помощью js?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть код, который может достать значение `select`:

```
 $('.resolve-selected-user-id').click(function() {
  let userId = $('.user-select option:selected').data('user-id');
  console.log('Selected user #' + userId);
    alert(userId);
    });
```

А дальше не знаю как поступить. Вот html код:

```
while ($row = $menu->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                        <input style="width: 30px" value="<?= 
$row['position'] ?>">

                        <select class="user-select">
                            <option data-user-id="<?=$row['id']?>"><?= $row['name'] ?></option>
                            <?$calc++;
                            $q = getMenu($type_object);
                            while ($pow = $q->fetch_assoc()) {
                                if ($pow['name'] != $row['name']) {
                                    ?>
                                    <option data-user-id="<?=$pow['id']?>"><?= $pow['name'] ?></option>
                                    <?
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>

                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign delPage"></span>
                        <br>
                    <? } ?>
```

Comment: В чем заключается проблема?

Comment: @Dmitry, не могу понять как составить этот массив с помощью js

Comment: Добавьте HTML-код формы.

Comment: @Dmitry, добавил

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно для каждой пары `input` и `select` получить значения и записать их в заранее созданный массив.

Чтобы определить пары лучше `input` и `select` одной строки обернуть в `<div>`.
Но можно воспользоваться тем, что [элементы соседние](http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/adjacent)

```
var result = [];

$('#form input').each(function () {
  result.push({
    input: $(this).val(),
    select: $('+ select', this).val()
  })
})
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает) Но появился еще один вопрос. На странице есть еще одна форма, при вызове функции, в массив записываются значения из всех форм. Можно это как-то исправить?

Comment: @r.mcreal можно, для этого у каждой формы должен быть свой `id`

Comment: а в вашем коде где добавить `id`?

Comment: @r.mcreal в `$('#form input')` `#form` это `id` элемента (формы)

Comment: В форме указал так `id="form"`, но не работает

Answer (score 1):

Я бы делал как-то так. Добавил имена и значения для инпутов и селектов. И значения бы сохранил в value.

```
<?php
$num = 0;
while ($row = $menu->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <input style="width: 30px" name="user_input_<?=$num?>" value="<?=$row['position'] ?>">

                        <select class="user-select" name="user_select_<?=$num?>">
                            <option data-user-id="<?=$row['id']?>" value="<?=$row['id']?>"><?= $row['name'] ?></option>
                            <?$calc++;
                            $q = getMenu($type_object);
                            while ($pow = $q->fetch_assoc()) {
                                if ($pow['name'] != $row['name']) {
                                    ?>
                                    <option data-user-id="<?=$pow['id']?>" value="<?=$pow['id']?>"><?= $pow['name'] ?></option>
                                    <?
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>

                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign delPage"></span>
                        <br>
<?php 
    $num++;
} 
?>
```

Сохранил максимальное значение номера

```
<script>
    var max_num = <?=$num?>;
</script>
```

и пробежался по всем полям и собрал их в массив

```
 $('.resolve-selected-user-id').click(function() {
    var res = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < max_num; i++) {
       //let userId = $('.user-select option:selected').data('user-id');
       //console.log('Selected user #' + userId);
       //alert(userId);

       var my_obj = {};
       var inp_val = $('[name=user_input_'+i+']').val();
       var sel_val = $('[name=user_select_'+i+']').val();
       my_obj.inp_val = sel_val;

       res.push(my_obj);
    }

    res; // то что надо 
});
```